# React & Ethereum Update Values in GUI

Tags: solidity

I am trying to update a value from the smart contract in te GUI - therefore I am using React.

I have the following event in my Smart Contract:

```
 event valueChange(uint old_value, uint new_value);
```

Im my DAPP I am listening to this event by the following lines of code (in the componentWillMount Method):

```
      //Event Triggering
  var myEvent = helloworldcontract.valueChange();

  myEvent.watch(function(error, result){

    if (!error) {

            console.log("New Value: " + result.args.new_value);

            console.log("Old Value: " + result.args.old_value);

            this.setState({lastNames: String(helloworldcontract.getText.call())})
    }
```

At the last line i get the following error

```
App.js:88 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

Do you know why I am getting this error? When I am using this line outside the Watch function it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

When you use a function as a callback, `this` no longer refers to the same scope.

What you can do is something like

```
var myEvent = helloworldcontract.valueChange();
var _this = this;

myEvent.watch(function(error, result){

     if (!error) {

        console.log("New Value: " + result.args.new_value);

        console.log("Old Value: " + result.args.old_value);

        _this.setState({lastNames: String(helloworldcontract.getText.call())})
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx! that works now!